Stripe Webhook events not sending (Test mode)
I setup my Stripe Connect account and tried seting up a webhook for a few simple events like checkout.session.completed. My event destination is an API Gateway endpoint that has SQS and lambda in the backend. I tested this seperately with Postman and I see the events without issues.
The issue seems to be Stripe not sending the events. In the "Events" tab, I see the events that I trigger BUT in the "Webhooks" tab under my event destination and "Event deliveries" tab, there is nothing. Everything request seems to have succeeded in the "Logs" tab and there is nothing in the "Errors" tab. I also made sure that the webhook is set for "Connected accounts" events and that it is not Disabled. I have not yet secured this so it shouldn't have anything to do with my backend rejecting the calls.
What could be the issue?





I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe support (via https://support.stripe.com/contact/login) for help here or chat with Stripe Engineers via the Stripe Discord (https://discord.com/invite/stripe) for something like this.
